# Authorization using AD groups to access different pages in static web app using cognito ,ELB,Lambda

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I have implemented user authentication with cognito and Azure AD (SAML) for static app running on EC2 instance in apache server.
I want to authorize user from AD group to access specific url from static web app.
For example : for users in admin group can only access pages with path /admin/*

For authentication I used ELB authenticate action which is working fine
Now I want to provide group based access to pages for static app running in apache running in ec2 instance.

Is there any with which I can authorize users without making any changes on application side. ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi @madhura1499, if the provided answer resolved your issue, you may mark it as answer or upvote it so that others who encounter the similar issue, it may be useful for them or community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you **create user pools supported by Amazon Cognito and authenticate them using corporate identities of Microsoft Azure AD**. Thus, for this purpose, you will have to **create user pools first in Amazon Cognito which are in fact nothing but groups containing user identities**. For this purpose, kindly refer to the link below for more details on its configuration: -

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-cognito-user-pools.html**

•   Once you are done with the above, you can **configure authentication for users using an application load balancer or elastic load balancing as you have done in case of users from Azure AD using Amazon Cognito**. For `configuring the user pool authentication in Amazon cognito, you will have to prepare to use an OIDC-compliant IdP, prepare to use for Amazon CloudFront and other things like user claims encoding and signature verification like that for user authentication`. For this purpose, to configure the same, kindly refer to the below AWS documentation link given: -

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html**

Comment: Hi @KartikBhiwapurkar, Actually I implemented in the same way as explained in your answer. Actually Authentication with ELB is working fine . But I want to restrict access to certain group for pages. 
For eg. Right Now All users from AD are able to access(After authentication on ELB) all pages of static app running in EC2. but the thing is after authentication I want to restrict the access based on AD groups.

Comment: Means , After authentication only members of AD group "abc" should be able to access pages starting with path https://ipaddress/home/abc/*
Since the app running on EC2 is simple static content  hence I can not add authorization layer on application side.

Comment: Even creating user pools by adding the required IdP didn't help you??? Because, in my answer, I have mentioned the process of configuring authentication for users through Amazon cognito and then creating user pools of these users and further adding them as groups.

Comment: Yes , If I understand correctly , As per your explanation , I created one user pool and joined that with Azure AD  with SAML .
then I configured ELB listener authentication to allow users from the above pool.


authentication is working as expected.

But now 
I want to further restrict access to certain users from above pool.
How to achieve that without making changes to application source code ?

Comment: And One more thing , I can not use cloudfront or api gateway because my application is static and hosted inside internal nnetwork

Comment: According to this documentation reference link: - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html, you will have to create rules in load balancer for user authentication, also you will have to enable an internal facing load balancer for this purpose.

Comment: yes , I  did that it is authenticating users from AD properly but now for certain users I want to restrict access .
Let suppose user A, and user B both are authenticated(cognito) in ELB ,then I want to create on more layer of authorization. For example , if users A and B , belong to group X then access is granted on the path

Comment: Then, can't you pool users in a user pool for that purpose. Because, that's what the link says so during adding users in the internal load balancer for that purpose.

Comment: yes , I used but it is doing successful authentication , I want to achieve group based authorization after successful authentication. The documentation talks about authentication not authorization